# View Call Hierarchy in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

Is there anybody who knows, what is for, and how it works, the "Call Hierarchy" window in Visual Studio (2010)?

[image]

**@SLaks :**
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<strike>I don't know why it isn't in your context menu, but you can also press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>T</kbd> when the cursor is on a method name to activate it.</strike>
**EDIT**: [It's not available in VB.Net](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/collaborate/connect-redirect).

It will show you every method that calls your function, and every method that your function calls.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd409859.aspx
[image: Screenshot]
<sub>(source: [microsoft.com](http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/dynimg/IC263182.png))</sub>

Comment: so, this "feature" Microsoft "Won't fix"... this is a discrimination for VB users... ((

Comment: @serhio apparently also UWP developers, which should be what their focus is on...